# Why do my android home screen widgets becoming slow?

Tags: android, performance, android-widget, android-adapterview

I've developped some homescreen widgets displaying an adapterviewflipper layout. They automatically start and have a flip interval of 3 seconds. They display a small collection with custom animation in and out animation (total time 2 seconds). The collection data is refreshed each minute.

After some indeterminate time the flip interval is getting bigger and can take about 17 seconds to animate. I dont understand why.

Is there an android limitation ? Memory leak issue ?
If i restart the phone, time is respected but i will encounter the issue in a near future.

Widget Layout

```
<AdapterViewFlipper
        android:id="@+id/calendar_widget_adapterViewFlipper"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:autoStart="true"
        android:flipInterval="3000"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
        android:inAnimation="@animator/slide_in_bottom"
        android:outAnimation="@animator/fade_out"
        />
```

AppWidget Provider

```
 @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        //Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Received intent " + intent);

        switch (intent.getAction()){
            case ACTION_MESSAGE_DATA_UPDATE :

                ComponentName thisAppWidget = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(), getClass().getName());
                AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
                int ids[] = appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetIds(thisAppWidget);
                for (int appWidgetID: ids) {
                    appWidgetManager.notifyAppWidgetViewDataChanged(appWidgetID, R.id.calendar_widget_adapterViewFlipper);
                }

                break;
...
```

App Widget Provider configuration file

```
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:initialKeyguardLayout="@layout/calendar_widget"
    android:initialLayout="@layout/calendar_widget"
    android:autoAdvanceViewId="@id/calendar_widget_adapterViewFlipper"
    android:minWidth="250dp"
    android:minHeight="50dp"
    android:minResizeWidth="250dp"
    android:minResizeHeight="50dp"
    android:previewImage="@drawable/calendar_ori_portrait"
    android:resizeMode="horizontal|vertical"
    android:updatePeriodMillis="0"
    android:widgetCategory="home_screen|keyguard"></appwidget-provider>
```

CalendarWidgetRemoteViewsService

```
public class CalendarWidgetRemoteViewsService extends RemoteViewsService {

    @Override
    public RemoteViewsFactory onGetViewFactory(Intent intent) {
        return new CalendarWidgetRemoteViewsFactory(this.getApplicationContext(), intent);
    }

}

class CalendarWidgetRemoteViewsFactory implements RemoteViewsService.RemoteViewsFactory {

    private Context mContext;
    private int mAppWidgetId;

    private List<WidgetItem> mWidgetItems = new ArrayList<WidgetItem>();

    public CalendarWidgetRemoteViewsFactory(Context context, Intent intent) {
        mContext = context;
        mAppWidgetId = intent.getIntExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        // In onCreate() you setup any connections / cursors to your data source. Heavy lifting,
        // for example downloading or creating content etc, should be deferred to onDataSetChanged()
        // or getViewAt(). Taking more than 20 seconds in this call will result in an ANR.

    }

    @Override
    public void onDataSetChanged() {
        // This is triggered when you call AppWidgetManager notifyAppWidgetViewDataChanged
        // on the collection view corresponding to this factory. You can do heaving lifting in
        // here, synchronously. For example, if you need to process an image, fetch something
        // from the network, etc., it is ok to do it here, synchronously. The widget will remain
        // in its current state while work is being done here, so you don't need to worry about
        // locking up the widget.

        //Log.d("CWRVS", "onDataSetChanged begins");

        final int[] ErrorCode = {0};
        mWidgetItems.clear();


        if (!UtilsHelper.isOnline(mContext)){
            ErrorCode[0] = 1;
        }

        if (ErrorCode[0] == 0)
        {
            final CountDownLatch latchSignal = new CountDownLatch(1);

            AuthenticationHelper authenticationHelper = AuthenticationHelper.getInstance(mContext);
            authenticationHelper.acquireTokenSilentlyWithAccountCheck(new AuthenticationCallback() {

                @Override
                public void onSuccess(AuthenticationResult authenticationResult) {
                    //Log.d("AUTH", "onSuccess");
                    final GraphHelper graphHelper = GraphHelper.getInstance();

                    graphHelper.getAllCalendarsEventsSupEqToday(authenticationResult.getAccessToken(), new ICallback<List<WidgetItem>>() {
                        @Override
                        public void success(List<WidgetItem> lwi) {
                            mWidgetItems = lwi;
                            latchSignal.countDown();
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void failure(ClientException ex) {
                            //Log.e("GRAPH", "Error getting events", ex);
                            latchSignal.countDown();
                        }
                    });
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(MsalException exception) {
                    //Log.d("AUTH", "onError");

                    //if ( exception.getErrorCode() == AuthenticationHelper.NO_CLIENT_ACCOUNT_REGISTERED  ){

                    //}
                    ErrorCode[0] = 2;
                    latchSignal.countDown();
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancel() {
                    //Log.d("AUTH", "onCancel");

                    latchSignal.countDown();
                }
            });
            //}



            try{
                latchSignal.await(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e){
                Log.e("CDN", "CountDownException", e);
            }
        }


        //Sending BroadCast for Error
        Intent ErrorIntent = new Intent(mContext, CalendarWidgetProvider.class);
        ErrorIntent.setAction(CalendarWidgetProvider.ACTION_CALENDAR_DATA_PARTIAL_UPDATE);

        Bundle extras = new Bundle();
        extras.putInt(CalendarWidgetProvider.EXTRA_ERROR_CODE, ErrorCode[0]);
        ErrorIntent.putExtras(extras);
        mContext.sendBroadcast(ErrorIntent);


        //Log.d("CWRVS", "onDataSetChanged ends");



    }


    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        // In onDestroy() you should tear down anything that was setup for your data source,
        // eg. cursors, connections, etc.
        mWidgetItems.clear();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mWidgetItems.size();
    }

    @Override
    public RemoteViews getViewAt(int position) {
        // position will always range from 0 to getCount() - 1.
        // We construct a remote views item based on our widget item xml file, and set the
        //

        if (this.getCount() == 0){
            return null;
        }

        WidgetItem wi =  mWidgetItems.get(position);
        RemoteViews rv = wi.BuildRemoteViews(mContext, position, this.getCount());

        // You can do heaving lifting in here, synchronously. For example, if you need to
        // process an image, fetch something from the network, etc., it is ok to do it here,
        // synchronously. A loading view will show up in lieu of the actual contents in the
        // interim.

        // Return the remote views object.
        return rv;
    }

    @Override
    public RemoteViews getLoadingView() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return 1;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return true;
    }


}
```

I expect the flipinterval respect its value.

Regards

Comment: Sounds like some garbage is building up somewhere. You could test that theory by omitting all collection refreshes (besides the first one), or by greatly increasing the collection data refresh interval. Can we see your `ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE` handler implementation?

Comment: Hi @greeble31, i havent implemented ACTION_MESSAGE_DATA_UPDATE. On the onReceive function, the broadcast message which update my collection is corresponding to ACTION_MESSAGE_DATA_UPDATE.
This message is sent each minute by an alarm manager and ask my RemoteViewsFactory to make a webrequest in order to update its AdapterViewFlipper items collection.

I make some recent tests and ive got a doubt on android:autoAdvanceViewId. It seems i dont need that as ma adapterViewFlipper has an autostart property. Do you think this could be 2 conflictual settings ?

Comment: Let's see your `RemoteViewsFactory` and the code concerning that web request, then. I don't know if those settings conflict or not, but you could easily test each one to determine if either is necessary.

Comment: I ve just edited the question with the remoteviewsFactory. Inside you can see webrequest using microsoft msal and graph api. I can paste code for this but it will be a lot to read. 
Ive updated the app (about those 2 settings i suspect conflictual) on the play store to check on my running android device. give feedback in some hours to see if the widgets still becoming slow.

Comment: Don't you think it's a bit coincidental, that you've noticed the widget taking 17 seconds to update, and you time out your connection in 15?

Comment: I can't necessarily see your problem, but you should add some information to the question about whether these network requests are succeeding or failing. Also, I would not return `true` from `hasStableIds()`, here, but that's probably not your problem. Things will be much easier for you if you do not rely on Google Play distribution to test each build. Consider adding a mock graph server to your dev network, or simply replace the network request with a synchronous method (for debug builds). You will be able to answer these questions much more quickly that way.

Comment: @greeble31 : you re probably right for the timeout connection. I must encounter an issue sometime with async graph queries ... I must to inspect more to understand what could happening. Mock data could be a smart solution for this.
Ive updated 3 hours ago and seems fine but for sure i have to make stronger test. I ll give feedback tomorrow. Ty for your assistance.

Comment: Well things seems to work fine now. Below the corrections i bring to the code :
+ unsetting android:autoAdvanceViewId
+ hasStableIds remains true but the getItemId is now implemented to be sure that the widget item is relevant 
+ rebuilding comletely the remoteviews as the appwidgetprovider can be garbage collected and no widget/remoteview error could appear after a device sleep time.

Ty again @greeble31. Your comments help me a lot in particulary to try to better understand how it works and for hasStableIds ...

Comment: No problem, have fun.